# How to reinitialize a Fortran function at each time step

Tags: function, performance, loops, fortran, gfortran

I have a program as follows:

```
Integer N,tmax
parameter (N=10,tmax=10)
real :: L,dt,noise,positions(tmax,N),positions0(N),s,force
integer :: param
force=0
L=100.0
dt=0.1
param=0
r=0
!initialization
do 1 i1=1,N
param=param+100
positions(1,i1)=(ran2(param)-0.5)*L
1 continue
positions0=positions(1,:)
!time dependent process
do 2 i2=1,tmax
    do 3 i3=1,N
    param=param+100
    force=0
    noise=0
    call routine_interaction(i3,N,positions0,force)
        noise=(ran2(param)-0.5)*L/10
        positions(i2,i3)=positions0(i3)+dt*(noise+force)
3   continue
positions0=positions(i2,:)
2 continue
print*, positions(1,:)
print*, positions(tmax,:)
end
```

with the subroutine and function:

```
      FUNCTION ran2(idum)
      INTEGER idum
!The ran2() subroutine from Numerical Recipes
!  (C) Copr. 1986-92 Numerical Recipes Software #$!5,5.){2p491&&k"15.  page 272
      END   


subroutine routine_interaction(ii,N,positions0,force)
integer N,ii
real :: r,s,force
real positions0(N)

        do 4 i4=1,N 
            if (ii.ne.i4) then
                r=abs(positions0(ii)-positions0(i4))
                s=sign(1.0,positions0(i4)-positions0(ii))
                force=force-(1/r**4-1/r**2)*s
            end if
4       continue
return
end
```

as you can see, the subroutine `routine_interaction` is called at each time step, so that at each time step, there are 2 iterations and `NxN=N²` calculations.

Is there a way in fortran to define a function at each time step, that would be defined as: `new_function(ii)=routine_interaction(ii,N,positions0,force)` and that would be called in the `do` loop `3`. It would lead to `N+N` calculations at each time steps?

Comment: Please use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions. And avoid any "Fortran:" in the title, it is just noise. The important bit is the tag below.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you are trying to ask. Can you rephrase it to make it clearer? Also note you have just put source for copyrighted software in a place accessible to all. You might want to think if this is a good idea - especially since Fortran has an in built random number generator that may well be good enough for your needs.

Comment: Indeed you violated the copyright of Numerical Recipes by posting the code here under a different license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use this algorithm, there is no way to reduce the force calculation (`routine_interaction`) to `O(N)` time. You have `N` elements in `positions0`, and you are calculating the distance `r` between each element and each other element (`r=abs(positions(ii)-positions0(i4))`). This requires at least `N*(N-1)/2` calculations.

You can somewhat reduce the number of calculations using a triangular loop, e.g. as

```
program p
  implicit none
    
  integer, parameter :: N=10, tmax=10
  real :: L,dt,noise,positions(tmax,N),positions0(N),force(N)
  integer :: param
  
  L=100.0
  dt=0.1
  param=0

  !initialization
  do i1=1,N
    param=param+100
    positions(1,i1)=(ran2(param)-0.5)*L
  enddo
  positions0=positions(1,:)
  
  !time dependent process
  do i2=1,tmax
    force = routine_interaction(N,positions0)
    do i3=1,N
      param=param+100
      noise=(ran2(param)-0.5)*L/10
      positions(i2,i3)=positions0(i3)+dt*(noise+force(i3))
    enddo
    positions0=positions(i2,:)
  enddo
  
  print*, positions(1,:)
  print*, positions(tmax,:)
end program

function routine_interaction(N,positions0) result (force)
  integer, intent(in) :: N
  real, intent(in) :: positions0(N)
  real :: r,s,force(N)
  integer :: i3,i4
  
  force = 0
  
  do i3=1,N
    do i4=1,i3-1
      r=abs(positions0(i3)-positions0(i4))
      s=sign(1.0,positions0(i4)-positions0(i3))
      force(i3)=force(i3)-(1/r**4-1/r**2)*s
      force(i4)=force(i4)+(1/r**4-1/r**2)*s
    enddo
  enddo
end function
```

Comment: Ah, OK. That is what is being asked. A nit pick but I think I would say "If you use this algorithm there is no way to reduce ...". Given you have a 1/r**2 force term you shouldn't just truncate, but something akin to an modern Ewald or fast multipole could reduce the order. But how to do that is not a programming problem, so off topic here.